# Continuous Loop of Circular Text

Tags: adobe, after-effects

I have a text animation where the text is on a circular path (a mask). The intent is to export this as a GIF, so I want the text to rotate around the circular path indefinitely.

Currently, I'm using an expression on the First Margin property: time*75. This works well to get the text moving around the circular path, but when exporting it causes a jump as the first and last frame don't match.

Alternatively, if I use keyframes to animate by adding 3 keyframes and setting First Margin values of 0, 100, 0 I get an undesired effect where the text will rotate in one direction up to the middle keyframe and then rotate backwards to 0.

Is there a way to get a seamless loop in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

So moving text around a circle using the First Margin doesn't use degrees like 360, but rather a seemingly random number based on the size of your path/mask. What you can do is make sure the first keyframe is set to zero, then for the last keyframe, as you change the value you'll notice the little line that moves with the text around the circle - get it as close to vertical as you can.  Then, *with the playhead over one of the keyframes*, select both keyframes and drag the number value for First Margin until the text sits where you want it - This will adjust both selected keyframes together so it stays a perfect loop.

Another method I use when matching keyframes for tricky loops is to move the playhead to the last keyframe, duplicate the layer with ctrl+D, then press "[" to move the start of that top layer to the playhead.  Then you can lower the opacity to like 50% and use it as a reference to line up the last keyframe on the layer below, then delete the reference layer.

An important thing when making loops is to make sure the last keyframe is on the frame *after* your last viewable frame.  So you can move your playhead to the last keyframe, then go back 1 frame and press "N" to set the end of your work area.
Otherwise, if your first and last frame match then you'll have a slight stutter because there's 2 duplicate frames.